# C# switch-label systax

Tags: c#, switch-statement

What is the correct syntax of a case label. The C# specs say:

```
switch-statement:
switch   (   expression   )   switch-block
switch-block:
{   switch-sectionsopt   }
switch-sections:
switch-section
switch-sections   switch-section
switch-section:
switch-labels   statement-list
switch-labels:
switch-label
switch-labels   switch-label
switch-label:
case   constant-expression   :
default   :
```

So a case statement is 'case' followed by a constant followed by a :.
However in some code I downloaded from Microsoft on GitHub it has the following:

```
  switch (NavigationRootPage.RootFrame?.Content)
  {
    case ItemPage itemPage:
      itemPage.SetInitialVisuals();
      break;
    case NewControlsPage newControlsPage:
    case AllControlsPage allControlsPage:
      NavigationRootPage.Current.NavigationView.AlwaysShowHeader = false;
      break;
  }
```

In resharper it says that newControlPage is a variable that is never used.

So is the c# specs incorrect.

I just downloaded what I thought was the latest version from MS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the new pattern matching syntax introduced in C# 7. It basically tests what type `NavigationRootPage.RootFrame?.Content` is. If it is `ItemPage` for example, then its value is put into a variable named `itemPage`. This is handy because you don't have to use `is` and `as` operators to check for each type and cast.

You won't find that in the language spec because the latest official release of the spec is for C# 5. [I know they are drafting a spec for C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/), but I haven't heard anything about the spec for C# 7. If you just want to look at the spec for the pattern matching syntax, the proposal can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/patterns.md), as suggested by Camilo Terevinto.

To silence the warning, replace `newControlsPage` and `allControlsPage` with `_`.

Comment: I might also add that the code could be 'improved' by using `_` instead of `newControlsPage` and `allControlsPage`

Comment: @user2825546 If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!